# Passing C-initialized struct to embedded Ruby interpreter

Tags: ruby, embedding

I'm embedding Ruby in C and I need to pass a struct created in C to a Ruby script, where I want to work with struct values. I have successfully done this with struct declaration `rb_struct_define` and initialization `rb_struct_new`, but I'm unable to pass a struct which is defined in C-style (`struct Address {...}`).

I got some advice that this can be done with use of `Data_Wrap_struct`, but I'm unable to get it working.

My example code is here: https://gist.github.com/1641269

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you pass to a Ruby method needs to be a Ruby object, you can't directly pass a C struct object.

What you can do is create a wrapper object for your struct that will provide Ruby code access to its members. Unfortunately, as far as I'm aware, there's no way to automatically do this based on the members of the struct. You'll have to write the C code to define the appropriate methods, which might get a bit tedious if your struct has a lot of members.

The `Data_Wrap_Struct` macro is what you use to wrap the C struct in a Ruby object. You can then use `Data_Get_Struct` in the implementations of the methods to unwrap the struct and get at the data.

[Here's an example](https://gist.github.com/1643711) that should hopefully point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much, your example is perfect and definitely points me to the right direction. I was looking for something like this for hours.